# How to Update a row if at least one field has changed - and return back all changes in laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, insert-update

I am following this [post](https://medium.com/@JinoAntony/10-hidden-laravel-eloquent-features-you-may-not-know-efc8ccc58d9e) in order to update a row if any field has changed.

```
//Retrieve an array from an API
$fields = ['field1'=>var1, 'field2'=>var2, ...];

$row = MyModel::ofField1($this->field1)->ofField2($fields['field2'])->first(); //Selects the row under field1 AND field2 condition. It is working.
$row->updateOrCreate($fields);//Should assign the new values to the model (but not persist)

//Next line should compare the model with what we have in the
//database. At least 1 value from the incoming array is different from what 
//we have in the database - so Update the row with the new value.
if($row->isDirty()){
   $row->save();
}
```

This is not working what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

`->updateOrCreate()` will persist the data (which you have mentioned you do not want to do).

This method has two arguments:

- One to query rows with certain field values
- The other for data to be used to update/create a record

In this case, if you are just checking if one of two fields have been updated, you should check if the specific field has been updated using `->isDirty($field)`:

```
$row = MyModel::first();

if ($row->isDirty('field1')) {
    $row->field1 = $fields['field1'];
}

if ($row->isDirty('field2')) {
    $row->field2 = $fields['field2'];
}

$row->save();
```

As you may have many fields returned from the api, you could loop through and check:

```
$row = MyModel::first();

foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
    if ($row->isDirty($field)) {
        $row->$field = $value;
    }
}

$row->save();
```